# Storing, retrieving, appending, and editing data stored in a text file with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, arraylist, text-files

I made a simple task manager app that can add, remove, and edit previously added tasks. The tasks are stored in a list, and are retrieved from it when any of the functions are called to an input. So in order to make sure that the added data isn't lost when the app is closed, I tried storing the list to a text file, and retrieving it. But when I'm calling the view function, without adding any data, having some tasks added when the app was opened the previous time, it shows no tasks. I tried the following solution, but it gave no results.

```
import json
tasks = []
with open("File.txt", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    tasks.append(file)
    print(tasks)
```

This printed nothing. Please point out if I made any mistakes here. If the purpose of this piece of code is achieved, my problem would be solved.

Comment: You are adding the (read out) `file` instance - a file handle ... not the `data` you read. ==> fix `tasks.append(file)`  to  `tasks.append(data)`

Answer (score 1):

I've tried something for you.

I've got a 'File.txt' with some contents (copied random example from https://json.org/example.html)

When I perform your code the result is

```
[<_io.TextIOWrapper name='File.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>]
```

I think what you want to see are the contents, so I changed

```
tasks.append(file)
```

to

```
tasks.append(data)
```

Now the output are the actual contents of the file when printed. I'm not sure if this is the result you need, because the lay out is still crappy, but that's content dependent ofcourse.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually wrote tasks.append(data), then print(tasks). But it prints nothing to the console. I'm using SublimeText3 btw.

Comment: Are you sure your file has content? Just open it with a regular text editor to check this. There is nothing special about the code that could go wrong I guess. Did you check if the file exists in the folder where the file is loaded (it should, or you should've gotten an error)

Comment: Yup... The file has content, and is present in the same director/folder as the python file. According to the code, it was supposed to insert the contents in that list which was supposed to get printed. But it shows no errors, and neither it prints out anything.

Comment: try this code: 'import os print(os.getcwd())'. This will print the current directory, if it's the right directory, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: It is the right directory. I've decided to try database instead of lists n textfiles.